# add column to an other table but without values and the same structure with vba or sql

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I want to add a column from the table1 to table2.
It shall have the same structure, which means afterwards all Attributes have to be the same. And the other point is that the new column shall be empty, without any values from table2.
I work with MS Access 2007. Can anyone help me?

Comment: First read this [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then rewrite your question and show what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to add fields to a given table you might go like this

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim t1 As DAO.TableDef
    Dim t2 As DAO.TableDef
    Dim col1 As DAO.Field
    Dim col2 As DAO.Field

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set t1 = db.TableDefs("Tabelle1")
    Set col1 = t1.Fields("TestColumn")

    Set t2 = db.TableDefs("Tabelle2")
    Set col2 = t2.CreateField(col1.Name, col1.Type, col1.Size)
    col2.Required = col1.Required
    'Add any property you want to clone
    t2.Fields.Append col2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

DoCmd.RunSQL ("create table table1 as select * from table2 where 1 =2 ;")

Comment: I think the OP wants to "clone" one column to a given table. Your code would create a completely new table with identical structure...